# Graded rings and weighted projective spaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, graded-rings

I am genuinely struggling with this concept, partly because of the language of graded rings.

So, I will ask a simple question. If polynomial rings $\mathbb{k}[x_0,x_1]$ and $\mathbb{k}[y_0,y_1]$ with associated weighted systems $S(1,1)$ and $S(2,2)$. Can I say that in the weighted systems there is an isomorphism of graded rings since I can define a map $\phi: x_0,x_1 \mapsto y_0,y_1$ which will preserve homogeneity?

This induces an isomorphism of weighted projective spaces $\mathbb{P}(1,1)$ and $\mathbb{P}(2,2)$.

Thus allowing us to saying that $\mathbb{P}(a_0,...,a_n)$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}(qa_0,...,qa_n)$.

I am asking this silly question because some texts ask for degrees to be preserved for an isomorphism graded rings

Comment: So,  what I have described in not preserving grading. This not an isomorphism of graded rings. However, if I describe $[x_0,x_1] \rightarrow [x_0^2,x_1^2]$ , would be my isomorphism of weighted projective spaces. @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez. Also, are you saying that the graded rings $S(1,1)$ and $S(2,2)$ cannot be isomorphic  due to the grading.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I am glad you have stated your answer in this form. Because I have asked a similar question with regards to a well established paper. Please https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4823825/weighted-projective-spaces-iano-fletcher