# Weighted projective spaces Iano-Fletcher

Tags: algebraic-geometry, graded-rings

I believe a statement in this Ian fletcher notes is [Iano fletcher](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/%7Emasda/Unpub/CPR_book/Fletcher.pdf) paper on Weighted projective spaces is wrong. For lemma 5.5 he states that the  Proj$S(a_0,...,a_n)$ is isomorphic to Proj$S(qa_0,...,qa_n)$. He states this is because the graded rings $S(a_0,...,a_n)$ and $S(qa_0,...,qa_n)$ are isomorphic.

This is clearly wrong, as we will not be able to define a graded isomorphism that preserve grading.

Please could I have some clarification and why has no one spotted this clear error.

Comment: The grading on a graded ring is well-defined only up to scaling so $\mathbb{C}[x^2,y^2]$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[z,w]$ as a graded ring. If that makes you uneasy just remember that the Proj construction is insensitive to rescaling the grading.

Comment: @ParthShimpi. Yes, but this does not prove $\mathbb{P}(1,1)$ is iso to $\mathbb{P}(2,2)$

Comment: @ParthShimpi, I am confused are you agreeing with me, that the statement is wrong or saying something else?

Comment: I’m saying the “degree 1” part of $\mathbb{C}[x^2,y^2]$ has basis $\{x^2,y^2\}$. Thus the obvious ring isomorphism between $\mathbb{C}[x^2,y^2]$ and $\mathbb{C}[z,w]$ is also an isomorphism of graded rings and so induces an isomorphism $\mathbb{P}(2,2)\cong \mathbb{P}(1,1)$.  In particular there is no mistake in the notes.